# Point to a Local file Within PHP Zend Framework for jQuery .Load

Tags: php, jquery, html, zend-framework

I am trying to figure out how to point to a file locally with this PHP Zend framwork site I have. For example the file structure is like this:

> public_html/application/views/index/filename1.phtml

within filename1.phtml I want to do a jQuery call to load an element from filename2.phtml but I am not sure how to call the local file structure as the structure listed above is not publicly available on the front end of the server. I would be able to access filename1.phtml by going to www.sitename.com/filename1

I hope this makes sense.

The jQuery call I want to use is this:

```
<script>
$('#div_id_for_filename1.phtml').load('path/to/filename2.phtml #div_id_for_filename2.phtml');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` `load` can only access something that is public ally available. if everything is in your public_html folder, though you have not specified the path to `filename2.phtml`, I am guessing it also lives at

```
public_html/application/views/index/filename2.phtml
```

so you would load it like

```
$('#div_id_for_filename1.phtml').load('/filename2.phtml #div_id_for_filename2.phtml');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery to call an action then render view file from that action.

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function rendercontentAction(){
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->render('filename');
    }
}
```